# Get "Log on as" value of a service with c#

Tags: c#, service

I would like to know who logged a certain service.
In order to do that I am using the class ManagementObject.
I would like to know how I can get this information.

```
            ManagementObject service2 = new ManagementObject(mp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you like to achieve is to get the User defined at the Service ("Logon as") which should start the service:

Simple way - read Registry - get the value of:

`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\{ServiceName}\ObjectName"`

Comment: Thanks a lot I was not in local machine but in current user.